# How do i define a directory in variable so as to back up file to?

Tags: backup, variable

I am trying to understand my logic in this very basic script.  I am trying to accomplish something extremely simple.  I am trying to copy `/var/log/messages` into a directory (under `/`) called `backup` as a file called `messages.txt`

**So here is the script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKP="$BACKDIR/$BACKFILE"

BACKDIR="/backup"

BACKFILE="messages.txt"

echo "Backing up files to $BACKP"

cp /var/log/messages $BACKP
```

**And here is my output:**

```
Backing up files to /
```

Furthermore, it copies the messages file to the root filesystem, which is totally NOT what i want.  I need to straighten out my logic, i have absolutely NO idea what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define things *before* you use them:

```
BACKDIR="/backup"
BACKFILE="messages.txt"
BACKP="$BACKDIR/$BACKFILE"
...
```

To expand a bit on the point, if the shell encounters this:

```
BACKP="$BACKDIR/$BACKFILE"
```

it gets the value of `BACKDIR` and the value of `BACKFILE` and substitutes them in. In your original example, both of these are undefined at the time that the shell encounters the BACKP assignment. The values of undefined variables in a shell program are replaced by *empty strings*, so the above assignment is equivalent to

```
BACKP="/"
```

If you define BACKDIR and BACKFILE first however, and *then* do the assignment to BACKP, as I do in the first part of this answer, their values are inserted and you end up with the equivalent of

```
BACKP="/backup/messages.txt"
```

which is what you want.

Comment: @Nick...and so in what way am I not doing that?

Comment: @Leonard your definition of `BACP` is using `BACKDIR` and `BACKFILE` before you've defined then.

Comment: @Leonard - what roaima said, but I also added a bit more detail. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @Nick  ....Ok, THAT certainly explains it, THANK you guys!!  ....I have to remind myself (especially when scripting) how Linux processes everything in strict logical order.

Comment: It's like in most programming languages: an assignment like that makes a copy of the current values on the right-hand side. (It's not a permanent two-way equivalence.) The only exception that comes to mind is Make, where nested references are evaluated when the variable is used.

Comment: It's not just Linux and it's not just scripting: most programming languages work this way (and shell *is* a programming language - where it is a bit different is in how it treats undefined variables).